# ASP.NET: How to specify which button should defaultly react for an Enter press?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have a webpage where there are two buttons and a textbox. When the page loads and user presses enter, the first button is clicked - and that is ok.

I would like to assure that if user enters the textBox and types anything there and THEN presses enter, the second button is clicked.
When I enter the textBox I can tell that the first button will be used when I press enter, because it is a bit dark-blue-bordered then.

I tried javascript's

```
if (event && event.keyCode == 13)
    document.getElementById("Button2").click();
```

but it somehow doesn't work. So my second thought was that there must be a possibility to tell the browser which button should defaultly react for an enter press when I'm in a specific textBox (the dark-blue-bordered button).

Edit: it might matter that first button is input and the second one is asp:Button

Edit2: Page.Form.DefaultButton is not an option, as there are somehow two default buttons. One should be clicked if user doesn't enter a textBox, other one if he is inside the textBox. Changing DefaultButton is not an option as this would require a postback after entering textBox by a user...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="Button2" >
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button2" OnClientClick="alert('Button2')"/>
</asp:Panel>
```

As soon as you start using the textbox - button2 will be the default button. Up until then the other button will be the default

Comment: @BritishDeveloper Sweet - I didn't know you could set the DefaultButton for an individual panel.

Comment: this is great, i didn't know about and that would be useful if... if it wasn't sharepoint-generated site that inside this panel has a control asp:Login with id "login" and a button that I am talking about, also with id "login"... and i cannot change that. So this is also not an option as setting DefaultButton="login" generated error as the Login control is found with this id.

Comment: In design view you can click on the login control and select "Convert to template" then you can get at that button's ID. Or do you not have access to the login control? (I'm not familiar with sharepoint)

Answer (score 2):

The `Page.Form.DefaultButton` allows to set which button will react to the `Enter` key.

Comment: please, read carefully! I don't want to change the default clicked button because when user presses enter after the page loads the first button should be clicked. The other button should be clicked only if the focus is on a textbox. I cannot use your code because this is a server code and I need to do this on a client

Answer (score 0):

DefaultButton property